# What happens when I use a subdomain ? How subdomain works?

Tags: dns

I wish to know how subdomain works. I will explain what I want to know: When there is a top-level domain like google.com, you can set its  DNS type A record or CNAME record to point it to an IP address (exemple: google.fr = 8.8.8.8 in a A record) But I want to know what happens when we use subdomains. Is it the same thing ? Do I point **video**.google.fr to is own DNS server (independent from google.fr top) to point to a record like a 9.9.9.9 server ?

I have seen [this answer](http://How%20to%20create%20a%20subdomain%20and%20how%20do%20they%20work?) to [How to create a subdomain and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032285/how-to-create-a-subdomain-and-how-do-they-work) but can I have different IP "A" for a subdomain per report of a top level domains. ?

Comment: There is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18128168/9334297

Comment: Yes but can I have different IP "A" for a subdomain per report of a top level domains. ?

Answer (score 2):

Apologies, I don't have enough reputation to comment.  To answer the question of creating a subdomain with a different IP outright, *yes* it is possible by using an A record.  Just create an A record with the subdomain name and the desired IP address.  It can be a completely different IP from the main domain's A record IP.

For a little explanation, there are multiple types of DNS records (e.g. A record, AAAA record, and CNAME record), each of which translate a domain name (or subdomain) into something different.  I have explained some below.

- **A record**:  translates a domain name or subdomain into an IPv4 address (the common 4 octet format such as `192.168.56.101`)
- **AAAA record**:  translates a domain or subdomain into an IPv6 address (the not as common format that looks like `2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348`)
- **CNAME record**:  translates a domain or subdomain into another domain or subdomain (these are used for aliases, such as the `www` subdomain of `example.com` pointing to `example.com` so that `example.com` and `www.example.com` go to the same location)

There are other records as well, but I'll leave that to Google for further explanation.  Once a domain name is purchased, subdomains can be created by using any of the above records depending on what the subdomain needs to translate to.  All that is necessary is to pick the correct one.

As a side note, creating a subdomain does not require creating **all** 3 record types as mentioned in a previous answer.  This **can** be done, but is not required.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need, for each sub-domain you want to have, to add an A, AAAA, CNAME records to your DNS settings in order to make it work.
I hope this answers your question.

I indeed forgot to say that an A record is for an IPv4 address.
AAAA for IPv6.